# How to add a path to system $PATH for all users's non-login shell and login shell on debian

Tags: debian, environment-variables, path

I installed some programs in /opt/my-program/bin, I wanted to add /opt/my-program/bin to system $PATH for all users's non-login shell and login shell. What should I do?

Changing /etc/environment is OK for non-login shell, but it does not work for login shell because Debian's /etc/profile (which will be sourced by login shell) will override the $PATH specified in /etc/environment.

Comment: If it's just a couple of binaries you want people to have access to, you can just symlink them to `/usr/local/bin` without altering environment variables.

Comment: Symlinks does not work because the files in /opt/my-program/bin use some shell script like `cd $(basedir "$0")`. Symlinks cause `$0` changes.

Comment: @user955091 I'd consider that a bug in the program. The standard technique is to look at the symlink target in such a case, precisely so that you can symlink the program in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.

Comment: Why not remove the assignment of `PATH` in `/etc/profile` (at least for non-root users)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `/etc/profile` source `/etc/bash.bashrc` by adding `[ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ] && . /etc/bash.bashrc` to the end of `/etc/profile`, then add your path changes to `/etc/bash.bashrc` with `PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path`

Comment: /etc/profile is not executed by non-login shell

Comment: I know - but `bash.bashrc` is which is why the path change should be added there and then make `/etc/profile` source `/etc/bash.bashrc` to make the changes for login shells as well.

Answer (score 6):

The `/etc/login.defs` file contains a default path as follows:

```
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Some of the variables are moving to the `pam` modules, but the `/bin/login` still has it's config file independent of users' shell.